# Early wakeups in WaitForSingleObject() ...?

Tags: windows, multithreading, time

Everything I've read both on the MS docs site (where it's not really addressed) and here in SO, says that Windows `WaitForSingleObject()` is not subject to spurious wakeups and it waits for at least the provided time, and maybe longer.  However, my testing says this is not true and in fact early wakeups almost always happen.  Is the "common wisdom" wrong and I just need to add loops to handle early wakeups, or am I doing something wrong and I need to keep banging my head on this to try to figure out?

Unfortunately the full code is too complex to post here, but I have two different threads each with their own event, created via:

```
event = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, NULL);
```

(event is a thread-local variable).  I have a mutex I use to ensure that both threads start running at about the same time.

In each thread I call `WaitForSingleObject()`.  In this specific test, I never call `SetEvent()` so the only way to finish is via timeout, and the return code shows that's what happens.  However, the actual amount of time spent waiting is massively variable and 90% of the time is *less* than the time I requested.  I've instrumented this using `QueryPerformanceCounter()` to detect how long is spent here and it's just wrong.  Here's the instrumented code:

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq, ctr1, ctr2;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

QueryPerformanceCounter(&ctr1);
DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(event, tmoutMs);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&ctr2);

uint64_t elapsed = ((uint64_t)ctr2.QuadPart - (uint64_t)ctr1.QuadPart) * 1000000ULL / (uint64_t)freq.QuadPart;
```

(here `elapsed` is kept in microseconds, just to be a bit more specific)
Then I print this info out.  In one thread `tmoutMs` is 2, and in the other thread `tmoutMs` is 100.  Almost every time the returned values are too short: the 2ms wait can take anywhere from 700us up, and the 100ms wait takes from about 93ms up.  Only once in 7 tries or so will the elapsed time be >100ms.  Here are some sample outputs:

```
event=104: pause(tmoutMs=2) => ret=258 elapsed us=169, ms=0
event=112: pause(tmoutMs=100) => ret=258 elapsed us=93085, ms=93

event=104: pause(tmoutMs=2) => ret=258 elapsed us=427, ms=0
event=112: pause(tmoutMs=100) => ret=258 elapsed us=94002, ms=94

event=104: pause(tmoutMs=2) => ret=258 elapsed us=3317, ms=3
event=112: pause(tmoutMs=100) => ret=258 elapsed us=96840, ms=96

event=104: pause(tmoutMs=2) => ret=258 elapsed us=11461, ms=11
event=112: pause(tmoutMs=100) => ret=258 elapsed us=105189, ms=105
```

The return code is always WAIT_TIMEOUT as expected.

Is this reasonable, even though it's not documented (or is it documented somewhere that I just can't find), and I just have to loop on my own to handle early wakeups?

FWIW, this is a C++ program compiled with Visual Studio 2017 running on Windows10.  It's a unit test program using Google Test, and has no graphical interface: it's command-line only.

Comment: By default, the system clock that's used by the scheduler ticks every 15.6 ms. See [wait functions and timeout intervals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/wait-functions#wait-functions-and-time-out-intervals) and [timer resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/timer-resolution). 6 ticks is 93.75ms.

Comment: I see.  I thought that might be the case but thanks for the pointers to the docs.  I sort of assumed that the functions would handle this by increasing the requested timeout so they don't return early, since they already document that they can return "late".  How can I find out what the current tick interval is?  I see that I can retrieve the min and max but is there a way to know what the current one is?  Then I can adjust the timeout myself...

Comment: I don't know of a documented Windows API function for this. The undocumented system call is `NtQueryTimerResolution(PULONG Maximum, PULONG Minimum, PULONG Current)`, which is in units of 100ns. This also returns the real maximum (e.g. 15.625ms) and minimum (e.g. 0.5ms) interrupt intervals that can be set via `NtSetTimerResolution(ULONG Desired, BOOLEAN SetResolution, PULONG Actual)`. `timeGetDevCaps` limits the minimum to 1ms and returns a maximum of 1000000ms, which I think is only relevant to the `udelay` parameter of obsolete `timeSetEvent`.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether the C++11 timeout methods (wait_for/wait_until with predicate, sleep_for, etc.) are implemented the same way, such that they may return early even if the predicate doesn't return true?  I mean, I know that due to unfixed bugs in Visual Studio these methods are unusable right now (which is why I'm trying to reimplement them using Windows-specific facilities) but I wonder if those methods adjust for this problem, beyond the bugs.  The C++ standard is pretty clear that these are not allowed to return early.

Comment: I don't know. In general, code that needs precise wait intervals, while still being reasonably efficient, can combine a dispatcher wait with a busy wait, using the system performance counter.

Comment: I don't need precise wait intervals, I just need the documented C++ behavior: the wait is guaranteed to be AT LEAST as long as requested, never shorter.  It can be longer, I don't care.  I don't want to reset the timing for the entire system.  I modified my WaitForSingleObject timer to round up to the next multiple of 15.6ms and that worked, BUT I tried the same thing with Sleep() and it didn't work: I want 150ms, I round up to 156ms which is 10x15.6ms, and it still times out early almost all the time.  I used NtQueryTimerResolution to verify my res is 15600us.

Comment: I don't think that's right. I think the kernel adds the desired wait time to the current interrupt time, i.e. the time of the last clock interrupt. If another interrupt is due soon, the wait might be satisfied almost a clock interval early. For example, say the timer resolution is 15.6ms and the current interrupt time is 0 and 0.1ms away from being updated to 15.6ms. Then the 156ms wait will be satisfied in 140.5ms (i.e. 9*15.6 + 0.1). In this case, add a full clock interval rounded up to the nearest integer number of milliseconds, i.e. if you need at least 150ms, then wait for 166ms.

Comment: That's what I did just because I'm tired of dealing with it.  But the Sleep() docs don't read (to me) like that is needed.  They say _If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. If dwMilliseconds is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on._  Based on experience you are probably right but that's not how the docs read unfortunately.  Cheers!